# apscheduler+scrapy+asyncio Can't execute first task smoothly

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, python-asyncio, apscheduler

version:
python 3.7、Scrapy 2.1.0、APScheduler 3.6.1

i create a simple spider for test

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com//']
    custom_settings = {
        'EXTENSIONS': {
            'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats': None,
        },
        'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('parse--------------------------')
```

run use the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor
install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler
from twisted.internet import reactor
configure_logging()
scheduler = TwistedScheduler(reactor=reactor)
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'interval', args=['test'], minutes=1, next_run_time=datetime.now())
scheduler.start()
reactor.run()
```

i want the spider run immediately，and then run every minute. 
the spider opened immediately ,but it seems the spider sleep until the next task run

```
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: testspider)
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.4.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Added job "CrawlerRunner.crawl" to job store "default"
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Scheduler started
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Looking for jobs to run
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Next wakeup is due at 2020-05-25 14:35:33.270223+08:00 (in 59.966950 seconds)
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Running job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2020-05-25 14:35:33 CST)" (scheduled at 2020-05-25 14:34:33.270223+08:00)
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'testspider',
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'testspider.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['testspider.spiders'],
 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-25 14:34:33 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2020-05-25 14:35:33 CST)" executed successfully
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Running job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2020-05-25 14:36:33 CST)" (scheduled at 2020-05-25 14:35:33.270223+08:00)
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'testspider',
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'testspider.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['testspider.spiders'],
 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-25 14:35:33 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Job "CrawlerRunner.crawl (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2020-05-25 14:36:33 CST)" executed successfully
2020-05-25 14:35:34 [test] INFO: parse--------------------------
2020-05-25 14:35:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-25 14:35:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 764,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 26324,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 61.426001,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 6, 35, 34, 905538),
 'log_count/INFO': 17,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 6, 34, 33, 479537)}
2020-05-25 14:35:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2020-05-25 14:35:35 [test] INFO: parse--------------------------
2020-05-25 14:35:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-25 14:35:35 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 764,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 26322,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.62243,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 6, 35, 35, 9694),
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 6, 35, 33, 387264)}
2020-05-25 14:35:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

If not used AsyncioSelectorReactor ，first task  will work smoothly

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the problem and solution:

First the solution: It seems that `scrapy.utils.reactor.install_reactor` uses `asyncioreactor` from the package `twisted.internet` and `asyncio` as a global variables and fails silently if it cant find it. So the right way to go would be:

```py
# asyncio reactor installation (CORRECT) - `reactor` must not be defined at this point
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/utils/reactor.html?highlight=asyncio%20reactor#
import scrapy 
import asyncio
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
scrapy.utils.reactor.install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
is_asyncio_reactor_installed = scrapy.utils.reactor.is_asyncio_reactor_installed()
print(f"Is asyncio reactor installed: {is_asyncio_reactor_installed}")
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

However, the following set of instructions fails:

```py
# asyncio reactor BAD INSTALLED (INCORRECT) Import order IS important
import scrapy 
import asyncio
from twisted.internet import reactor
scrapy.utils.reactor.install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
is_asyncio_reactor_installed = scrapy.utils.reactor.is_asyncio_reactor_installed()
print(f"Is asyncio reactor installed: {is_asyncio_reactor_installed}")
```

Its bad code, it should not be this way. I hope scrapy developers make this right soon.

Comment: Actually my code is consistent with yours.the log info "[scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor" means i have install AsyncioSelectorReactor successful.now i found a solution : use another task to "activate it".for example`sched.add_job(lambda :print('activate'), 'interval', minutes=1, next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))`

Answer (score 1):

It first waits the interval and only then runs the scheduled function. So it's working correctly. If you want to make it run immediately, add `next_run_time=datetime.now()` to you `add_job()` call.

Comment: This behavior will change with APScheduler 4.0 where it will start immediately by default.

Comment: look at the code and log ,i have add next_run_time=datetime.now() ,and the problem is first task run immediately ,but it pause halfway .

Comment: "it pause halfway" – please explain what you mean by that.

Comment: log info "Spider opened" means task start ,and "Spider closed" means stop ,Actually the  task will take about 2 seconds.the first task start at "34:33" and stop at "35:34" ,the second task start at "35:33" and stop at "35:35" .

Comment: the first task wont end until the next task start , if i set interval to minutes=10 ,the first task will take 10minutes+ ,so it seem that first task  pause halfway

Answer (score 1):

I found this old question, and it seems like the TwistedScheduler can't work very well with scrapy framework
This is my solution by using another thread only for APScheduler

```
import threading
from twisted.internet import reactor
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

runner = CrawlerRunner( YOUR_SCRAPY_SETTINGS )
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(
        lambda: reactor.callFromThread(lambda: runner.crawl('test')),
        trigger='cron', minute='*/1',
    )

scheduler_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: scheduler.start())
scheduler_thread.start()
reactor.run()
scheduler.shutdown()
```

References:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

https://docs.twisted.org/en/twisted-18.7.0/core/howto/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution,"use another task to activate it",for example:
add the task:

```
sched.add_job(lambda :print('activate'), 'interval', minutes=1, next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))
```